# What does the M/M in RJ45M/M mean?

Tags: cables, network-interface, cable-assemblies

I have what I've been told is one of these cables, but not sure what it means.

Comment: M/M means _male to male_. Never heard of an _RJ34_ cable before.

Comment: @m.Alin ah my fat finger typing, edited to 45 now, thanks

Comment: @m.Alin, sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Kortuk I have my doubts, but ok..

Comment: @m.Alin If I knew more I would say it but labeling cable is almost useless to discuss because there are not serious standards for that to my knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

M/M means *male to male* and it says that both ends of the cable have [male connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_connectors_and_fasteners#Electrical_and_electronic_connectors).

So you probably have just an usual Ethernet cable:

[image: Ethernet cable]

Comment: wow, they're big, aren't they? ;-)

Comment: Do you feel intimidated? :-)

Comment: True story: a friend of mine said this when a girl was passing, and got slapped in the face, haha. Is a running gag since.

Comment: Funniest thing is that he didn't mean the girl's... Anyway, we were discussing something else.